# Sharepoint List Settings Validation Formula Date validation

Tags: validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a very unique project I am working on to automate leave requests. Well its not unique but the validation I am trying to do is :)

So here it is,
I have two fields Start date and End date. Both fields are Date and Time. I am trying to write a formula that makes sure first that end date and start date are the same and end date cannot be older than start date. Then the hard part is end date with time must be greater than start date but cannot exceed start date by more than 10 hours.

So here is how it looks

Start date: 1/7/2015 9:00am

End Date: 1/7/2015 5:00pm

The issue is trying to validate the time and make sure it validates correctly. I hope this makes sense.

Here is my current formula that rejects everything.

```
=IF(INT(([End Date]-[Start Date])*24)>9,IF([Start Date]>[End Date],FALSE),FALSE)
```

I used this microsoft link as a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Raouf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Formula lacks the second parameter in the second IF

In my example I used Due Date because I tested it on a default Task List

```
=IF(([Due Date]-[Start Date])*24<10,
    IF([Start Date]<[Due Date],"Approved","Incorrect dates"),
    "Over 10 hours"
   )
```

This formula approves 23:00 to 01:00 as well.

You can check if it is the same date with:

```
=DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"d")
```

And then use the AND function to make your Formula a bit better readable

```
=IF(AND(
        ([Due Date]-[Start Date])*24<10,
        [Start Date]<[Due Date],
        NOT(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"d"))
       ),"Approved","Not Approved")
```

HTH

Danny